# How to solve sbt dependency conflict?

Tags: scala, sbt, sbt-assembly

I have this error when doing `sbt clean assembly`:

```
deduplicate: different file contents found in the following:
[error] /home/jack/.cache/coursier/v1/https/repository.rnd.transport.net/adata-sbt-producdataon/com/transport/data/data-scalaxb-abr_2.11/1.0.1/data-scalaxb-abr_2.11-1.0.1.jar:scalaxb/XMLStandardTypes$class.class
[error] /home/jack/.cache/coursier/v1/https/repository.rnd.transport.net/adata-sbt-producdataon/com/transport/data/data-scalaxb-datackedatang_2.11/0.12.0/data-scalaxb-datackedatang_2.11-0.12.0.jar:scalaxb/XMLStandardTypes$class.class
at sbtassembly.Assembly$.applyStrategies(Assembly.scala:142)
[error]         at sbtassembly.Assembly$.x$1$lzycompute$1(Assembly.scala:26)
[error]         at sbtassembly.Assembly$.x$1$1(Assembly.scala:24)
[error]         at sbtassembly.Assembly$.stratMapping$lzycompute$1(Assembly.scala:24)
[error]         at sbtassembly.Assembly$.stratMapping$1(Assembly.scala:24)
[error]         at sbtassembly.Assembly$.inputs$lzycompute$1(Assembly.scala:68)
[error]         at sbtassembly.Assembly$.inputs$1(Assembly.scala:58)
[error]         at sbtassembly.Assembly$.apply(Assembly.scala:85)
```

To solve this problem, i have tried added one of these blocks in `build.sbt`:

```scala
assemblyMergeStrategy in assembly := {
  case PathList("scalaxb", "XMLStandardTypes$class.class") =>
    MergeStrategy.first
  case x =>
    val oldStrategy = (assemblyMergeStrategy in assembly).value
    oldStrategy(x)
}
```

, or

```scala
libraryDependencies += ("com.transport.data" %% "data-scalaxb-datackedatang" % "0.12.0")
  .exclude("scalaxb", "XMLStandardTypes$class.class")
```

Nothing works.

I understand that there exist two versions of XMLStandardTypes class coming from `data-scalaxb-abr` and `data-scalaxb-datackedatang`, but even after i tried to use the merge strategy `first (or last, or discard)`, or even `exclude`, why it still persists? How can I solve this problem?

---

Update1:
It seems it happens in some machines but not some other machines, the merge behaviour depends on the machines. It happens in several local machines, but not in Jenkins agent. Does it give a hint?

Comment: What about full sbt file and versions about sbt, jdk etc.. would help here..

Comment: `sbt.version=1.3.7`, `java version "1.8.0_231"`

Comment: please share your `build.sbt` file. You can also use [sbt dependencyTree](https://www.baeldung.com/scala/sbt-dependency-tree) to debug transitive dependencies

Comment: I cannot share the full `build.sbt` due to enterprise confidential concern

Comment: from the dependency tree, i can clearly see that there exist two versions of the class coming from different JARs, but that's no surprise, the question is why the merge strategy cannot be applied, right?

Comment: Did you try to put logs in your merge strategy cases?

Comment: Should you put `ThisBuild` in front of `assemblyMergeStrategy`?

Comment: @GaëlJ yes, i put `assemblyMergeStrategy` at the end of build.sbt

Comment: What does the logs tell you then? Share the setup with logs and what logs you get.